# How to play 3gp file in Java?

Tags: java, media, jmf, 3gp

It is a Java question.
I try to use Fobs4jmf to play 3gp. I can see the video but without any sound.
Is there any solution?

And I try a newer library called xuggler, but I only see how to manipulate ,modify the video instead of playing a video file. Is it possible to use it play video,sound?

Here is the audio file that can not be played by Fobs4jmf  (Pure sound file)
http://gonow.no-ip.org/example.3gp

Thanks

Comment: Code would help, Also, do the files play in RealPlayer, VLC, etc

Comment: Thx, but it is because fobs4jmf not support this format.
And I now switch to VLCJ. I can play a 3gp file with both sound and video. But I still fail in playing 3gp with pure sound.

Here is the code:
http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/source/browse/tags/vlcj-1.1.5/vlcj/src/test/java/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/test/minimal/MinimalTestPlayer.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example.3gp, it states its properties as follows (using KMP Player):

```
C:\Documents and Settings\DEVELOPER\Desktop\example.3gp
   General
      Complete name : C:\Documents and Settings\DEVELOPER\Desktop\example.3gp
      Format : MPEG-4
      Format profile : 3GPP Media Release 4
      Codec ID : 3gp4
      File size : 5.23 KiB
      Duration : 3s 460ms
      Overall bit rate : 12.4 Kbps
   Audio #1
      ID : 1
      Format : AMR
      Format/Info : Adaptive Multi-Rate
      Format profile : Narrow band
      Codec ID : samr
      Duration : 3s 460ms
      Bit rate mode : Constant
      Bit rate : 5 200 bps
      Channel(s) : 1 channel
      Sampling rate : 8 000 Hz
      Resolution : 16 bits
      Stream size : 2.20 KiB (42%)
      Title : SoundHandle
      Writing library :
```

You can use libVLC/VLC library via VLCJ which is supposed to be able to open any media format and containers. But, the problem is that GPL version of libVLC/VLC doesn't support AMR audio format used in 3GP container due to following statment (from Wikipedia):

> To use AMR as audio codec, VLC and FFmpeg must be compiled with AMR
>   support. This is because the AMR license is not compatible with the
>   VLC license.

Moreover, when referring to this message http://mailman.videolan.org/pipermail/vlc-devel/2011-February/078807.html, it says:

> In any case, parsing AMR is done by libavformat and libavcodec from
>   the FFmpeg  project, not directly by the VideoLAN project.

Going through the message threads above, even if it is able to open AMR audio format via restricted version, it does have problem with AMR file seeking:

http://mailman.videolan.org/pipermail/vlc-devel/2011-February/078814.html

Comment: the coming libVLC version 1.2.0-pre1 shall be able to decode AMR audio